# Delete Confirmation Dialog using FancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I want to implement delete confirmation dialog using FancyBox. The scenario is to pass the url to FancyBox and go to url defined to run delete action when user press "Yes/Confirm" button. Any real example for this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe is this what you looking for: http://snipplr.com/view/29911/javascript-alert-and-confirm-dialog-the-fancybox-way/